# webpack is not running after starting separate expressJS service

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, bash, webpack

For some reason I do not see webpack being kicked off.  My script stops right after `yarn start` and never runs `webpack-dev-server --watch --env=dev --open` part of it in my `dev` script.  I suppose that's because the node service doesn't exit and continues to run so I never get a completion hence the `&& webpack-dev-server --watch --env=dev --open` never runs?

```
"start": "PORT=5000 nodemon --trace-warnings dist/server/server.js",
"build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --env=prod --watch && yarn compile-server && yarn start",
"dev": "NODE_ENV=development yarn lint && yarn copyData && yarn compile-server && yarn start && webpack-dev-server --watch --env=dev --open",
"compile-server": "tsc -b ./src/server",
    "copyData": "mkdir -p dist/shared/data && cp src/shared/data/companies.json dist/shared/data && cp src/shared/data/countries.json dist/shared/data",
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeJS is [single threaded](https://itnext.io/multi-threading-and-multi-process-in-node-js-ffa5bb5cde98). It never left nodemon.

Comment: ok so I might be able to use something like https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently#readme or https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all

Comment: so what's the solution if I want to run a rest service AND app at the same time with a script?  I need webpack to wait for the node service to finish running above...then run webpack

Comment: Are you trying to run the webpack-dev-server for your app and nodemon for your server?

Comment: yes exactly...I want to make sure nodemon sever is done and running before I run my webpack build.  I really don't wanna run them concurrently either I guess.  I want to ensure the service is up first and running to serve API requests from my bundle.

Comment: There are a couple solutions. Easiest is just run two separate command windows. Else, you could use webpack's nodemon plugin.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't a way to indicate that nodeman has finished loading. You can have webpack build then launch nodemon or run nodemon and webpack in parallel. Nodemon is fast so by the time the webpack build is complete, nodemon would already be capable to serving. So the npm-run-all would be my recommended solution.

Comment: >You can have webpack build then launch nodemon.  that wouldn't work in this case as I need nodemon to be done and they're separate services anyway.  But thanks.  >you could use webpack's nodemon plugin.  I don't see how that'd help me here, as my service is a completely separate service outside of webpack's development bundle